# Issue with XSLT and FOP when configuring XMLConstants.html#FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an issue when generating PDF from Java objects using XSLFO and XSLT:

I have this code:

```
TransformerFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl",
                    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
templates = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(PdfGenerator.class.getResourceAsStream(ORDERS_XSL)));
FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
Source src = getSourceForCommandList(commandeList);
try {
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

        templates.newTransformer().transform(src, res);
    } finally {
        out.flush();
    }
```

My xslt uses fo namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">



    <xsl:template match="orders">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4"
                    page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm"
                    margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="0.5cm" margin-right="0.5cm">
                    <fo:region-body />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="order" />
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
    ...
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works fine and generates a PDF from source Objects using Apache FOP and XSLT.

However, when I add this line to respect best practices regarding security:

> factory.setFeature([XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING), true);

It breaks because fo namespace is not loaded, I have those warning on template parsing:

```
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #67; "master-name" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #67; "page-height" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #67; "page-width" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #67; "margin-top" attribute is not allowed on the fo:simple-page-master element!
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, is it possible to set the namespace, prefix of the `formating object` in your SAXResult. I imagine you manipulate the Properties of said Object ... good luck :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was due to xalan TransformerFactory implementation being loaded instead of JDK's embedded one **com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl**

I excluded xalan from dependencies :

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

And it worked